# Compare large csv with a list and keep row with duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a script that runs everyday and outputs a CSV file with a bunch of lines.

Example:

CSV1

```
Access Point,MacAddress,Status,Site,Date
AP03 - 1695,5c5b352e3c9b,Disconnected,Store 1695,08-21-2019
AP01 - 0099,5c5b352e44b1,Disconnected,Store 0099,08-21-2019
AP07 - 1961,5c5b350eeae9,Disconnected,Store 1961,08-21-2019
AP05 - 3165,5c5b352e1f04,Disconnected,Store 3165,08-21-2019
AP02 - 1161,5c5b352e4484,Disconnected,Store 1161,08-21-2019
AP05 - 0249,5c5b352e40c9,Disconnected,Store 0249,08-21-2019
AP06 - 1057,5c5b352e1ed7,Disconnected,Store 1057,08-21-2019
AP01 - 2700,5c5b353e444d,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2700,5c5b352ea519,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2722,5c5b352eb446,Disconnected,Store 2722,08-21-2019
```

I want to keep only lines where the Macadress is in CSV0

CSV0

```
5c5b352e3c9b
5c5b350eeae9
5c5b352ea519
5c5b352eb446
```

Desired Output (something similar):

Compare CSV1 to CSV0, keep only lines with MacAddress in CSV0 :

```
AP03 - 1695,5c5b352e3c9b,Disconnected,Store 1695,08-21-2019
AP07 - 1961,5c5b350eeae9,Disconnected,Store 1961,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2700,5c5b352ea519,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2722,5c5b352eb446,Disconnected,Store 2722,08-21-2019
```

Problem : CSV1 is a large CSV file (nearly half-a-billion rows of csv data ) and i don't succeed to do the comparaison effciently.

Comment: The number of rows is insignificant. What is the size of the file? can it even be read all at once? If not, research reading it in chunks, this has been covered a lot here on SO.

Comment: This should be pretty easy with pandas. Put the values from CSV0 into a list, and use the pandas `.isin()` method to filter CSV1.

Comment: @Barmar Assuming the entire thing can fit in memory. I'm going to guess that it can't

Answer (score 1):

Load `CSV0` into a `set`. Then loop over `CSV1` testing if the MacAddress column is in the set.

```
import csv

with open("CSV0") as f:
    macaddresses = set(line.strip() for line in f)

with open("CSV1") AS f, open("CSV1.new", "w") AS f_out:
    csv1 = csv.reader(f)
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)

    for row in csv1:
        if row[1] in macaddresses:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
```